# Problems importing tf 2.3 graph into Tensorflow.NET

Tags: c#, tensorflow, .net-core

I have trained a model in Python using Tensorflow 2.3 and the Tensorflow Object Detection API. I save the model using the SavedModel format that gives me a .pb file. From there I am trying to use that graph in Tensorflow.NET. To do so I am trying to mimic one of the TensorFlow.NET examples (`DetectInMobilenet.cs`).

The example starts with `Run()`:

```
        public bool Run()
        {
            tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution();

            Predict();

            return true;
        }

        public Graph ImportGraph()
        {
            var graph = new Graph().as_default();
            graph.Import(Path.Join(modelDir, pbFile));

            return graph;
        }

        public void Predict()
        {
            // read in the input image
            var imgArr = ReadTensorFromImageFile(Path.Join(imageDir, picFile));

            var graph = ImportGraph();

            using (var sess = tf.Session(graph))
            {
                Tensor tensorNum = graph.OperationByName("num_detections");
                Tensor tensorBoxes = graph.OperationByName("detection_boxes");
                Tensor tensorScores = graph.OperationByName("detection_scores");
                Tensor tensorClasses = graph.OperationByName("detection_classes");
                Tensor imgTensor = graph.OperationByName("image_tensor");
                var outTensorArr = new Tensor[] { tensorNum, tensorBoxes, tensorScores, tensorClasses };

                var results = sess.run(outTensorArr, new FeedItem(imgTensor, imgArr));

                BuildOutputImage(results);
            }
        }
```

This works fine. So then I try to implement this in my solution.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution();
var graph = new Graph().as_default();
graph.Import(modelPath);
```

This gives this error: `Tensorflow.InvalidArgumentError: 'Invalid GraphDef'`. After Googling around, it looks like the format that `graph.Import()` is looking for is a frozen graph. But since I am using TF 2.3, it no longer supports saving in the frozen format and instead uses the SavedModel format.

Then I tried:

```
tf_with(Session.LoadFromSavedModel(modelPath), sess =>
            {
                Tensor tensorNum = sess.graph.OperationByName("num_detections");
                Tensor tensorBoxes = sess.graph.OperationByName("detection_boxes");
                Tensor tensorScores = sess.graph.OperationByName("detection_scores");
                Tensor tensorClasses = sess.graph.OperationByName("detection_classes");
                Tensor imgTensor = sess.graph.OperationByName("image_tensor");
                var outTensorArr = new Tensor[] { tensorNum, tensorBoxes, tensorScores, tensorClasses };

                var results = sess.run(outTensorArr, new FeedItem(imgTensor, image));
                return results;
            });
```

And this loads the model fine, but then says that this line `Tensor tensorNum = sess.graph.OperationByName("num_detections");` is throwing an error saying that `"num_detections"` is not found in the graph.

Do you guys have any suggestions on how to get this to work? And I am also open to different implementations as long as I can use .NET Core to do so.

Thanks!

Comment: did you ever figure out the issue?

Comment: Nope, sorry! I moved on to a different architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The input tensor is in operation named with "**serving_default_input_tensor**".

The inference outputs are in operation named with "**StatefulPartitionedCall**".

The output tensor names in **StatefulPartitionedCall** are as below:

- StatefulPartitionedCall:0 ('detection_anchor_indices')
- StatefulPartitionedCall:1 ('detection_boxes')
- StatefulPartitionedCall:2 ('detection_classes')
- StatefulPartitionedCall:3 ('detection_multiclass_scores')
- StatefulPartitionedCall:4 ('detection_scores')
- StatefulPartitionedCall:5 ('num_detections')
- StatefulPartitionedCall:6 ('raw_detection_boxes')
- StatefulPartitionedCall:7 ('raw_detection_scores')

The code snippet:

```
public void Test()
{
    var imgArr = ReadTensorFromImageFile(_testImg);
    using (var sess = Session.LoadFromSavedModel(Path.Combine(_modelSrcPath, _savedModel)))
    {
        var graph = sess.graph;
        
        var t0 = graph.OperationByName("StatefulPartitionedCall").outputs;
        
        Tensor tensorNum = t0[5];
        Tensor tensorBoxes = t0[1];
        Tensor tensorScores = t0[4];
        Tensor tensorClasses = t0[2];
        Tensor imgTensor = graph.OperationByName("serving_default_input_tensor").outputs[0];

        Tensor[] outTensorArr = new Tensor[] { tensorNum, tensorBoxes, tensorScores, tensorClasses };

        var results = sess.run(outTensorArr, new FeedItem(imgTensor, imgArr));

        Console.WriteLine(results);
        
        BuildOutputImage(results);

    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works until trying to get the results with gives an error of
``` Error while reading resource variable WeightSharedConvolutionalBoxPredictor/WeightSharedConvolutionalBoxHead/BoxPredictor/bias from Container ```

any ideas?